# Default 3d view of imported model (Bounding Box or Wireframe)

Tags: meshlab

After importing 3d model it's displayed in "Vert" mode (something like smooth shading mode). For very density mesh it's very slow... Even on powerfull PC.

I haven't found option (in Tools >> Options.. >> Global Parameters Window) for changing default state from "Vert" view to "Bounding Box" or "Wireframe"...
Does it's possible to force 3d View, to be, by default in "Bounding Box" or "Wireframe"?

Answer (score 0):

Not by default, but you can change to wireframe as soon as you launch meshlab and before of loading your mesh.